# Pdf To Text in android

Tags: android

Please help me about how I convert a pdf file to text(string or character) in android.I have tried using a jar file of jpedal.But it has a problem that decodePdf.openPdfFile(file_name) function does not work.It show a problem like that javax.swing required.How I can solve this?please help me.

Comment: you had not ask question in proper way but you question is right i am also finding it if you find then pls share with me

Answer (score 1):

I used google to find [Android PDF Library](http://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/mobile/android_pdf_library.html) it looks pretty solid. There are also a lot of previous [StackOverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665957/pdf-parsing-library-for-android) regarding this topic.

Comment: there are many post abou pdf reader but none can get solution if you have then please post it.